# Как в Firebase связывать профили с одним email'ом

Tags: android, firebase

Как в **Firebase** связывать профили с одним email'ом в один аккаунт с уникальным идентификатором?

**UPDATE**
Моё решение:
  1. В консоли Firebase разрешил регистрировать несколько аккаунтов с одинаковыми email-ами;
  2. Информацию о профиле храню в БД по ссылке **/users/id/**, где id это email, в котором символ '.' заменен на ',' (ибо Firebase не позволяет в ключе хранить символ '.';
  3. В итоге. При регистрации: по email'у получаю id и смотрю, есть ли запись **/users/id/**, если нет - создаем, если есть - просто забираем её. 
  При авторизации, вне зависимости от провайдера, получаю id по email'у и получаю запись **/users/id/**.
  4. Возможно, при формировании прав записи\чтения могут возникнуть проблемы. С этим моментом близко ещё не знакомился, не могу точно сказать.

Answer (score 1):

Для привязки используется функция  `FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)`

Порядок действий:

1. Авторизовать пользователя.
2. Предложить авторизоваться провайдером, который необходимо привязать к существующему.
3. Получить credentials. Для почты это:

   `AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getEmailAuthCredential(email, password)`
4. Вызвать `linkWithCredential()`

Документация:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

Comment: Не уверен, что аккаунты объединяются именно по email'у. А если мой друг с моего устройства зашел в свой аккаунт, то нельзя же объединять. профили. К тому же, как я понимаю, при каждой регистрации у **FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()** будет свой UID.

Comment: @differ связывается любой существующий провайдер с любым другим провайдером.